# Scale rectangle in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Any one please help me I'm going crazy!

I have a image loaded and the painted to a canvas element. In the image there's a rectangle. This rectangle is marked with two red dots. What I want to do is to scale the rectangle to fill the entire image. If you go to 
http://jsfiddle.net/arpo/v2Yrv/
you'll see what I mean. Drag the slider at top to see how the red dots goes from it original positions out to the corners. This is exactly how I want it to behave. But I cant get the rectangle to scale in this linear way. Instead it goes in a bow. :/

The scaling is made in the function scalePain.

Any one?

Comment: Interesting, I tried to edit your question to make things clear, but I couldn't. Tip: Edit your question, is kind jumbled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right way for your offsets calculation

```
offx = topx - tx - topx * scale;
offy = topy - ty - topy * scale;
```

Please, see your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2Yrv/1/)

Comment: Had to search in stack overflow to find out how :) Thanx again!